# Is it guaranteed that intptr_t safely roundtrips through uintptr_t?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Can I take an `intptr_t` and assign or memcpy it to a `uintptr_t` and back again and be guaranteed to end up with the same value?

That is, are either of the following guaranteed to work (no assert):

**Using assignment:**

```
intptr_t i1 = f();
uintptr_t u = i1;
intptr_t i2 = u;
assert(i1 == i2);
```

**Using `memcpy`:**

```
intptr_t i1 = f();
uintptr_t u;
memcpy(&u, &i1, sizeof(u));
memcpy(&i2, &u, sizeof(u));
assert(i1 == i2);
```

If it is not guaranteed by the standard, it is possible to check a condition at compile or runtime to determine whether it is guaranteed on a particular platform.

Comment: Under which standard revision?  It looks like it may be guaranteed by C++20, but not before.

Comment: @NateEldredge, anything from C++11 forward. So an answer like "Not until C++20" would be fine.

Answer (score 4):

The `memcpy` is guarenteed to work, as it treats the values as a sequence of bytes.  The assignment is not guarenteed to work, though will generally work on any machine that uses 2s complement integers.  A machine that uses 1s complement or sign-magnitude will change the value of -0 to 0, though the assert will still be ok, since -0 == 0 is true.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should have used a memcmp() rather than == in the assert, although that of course raises a whole different set of questions!

Comment: In C++ there would be shortly no 1's complement possible by C++20 standard, no?